# Error happened install Tensorflow with unknown reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I have tried several times installing tensorflow on my Mac, my python version is 3.7.9,
TensorFlow is supported Python 3.5–3.8 (to my knowledge), and I keep get error when the process run about half:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 437, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 461, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 505, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 228, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 183, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 388, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/legacy/resolver.py", line 340, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 469, in prepare_linked_requirement
    hashes=self._get_linked_req_hashes(req)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 259, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 130, in get_http_url
    link, downloader, temp_dir.path, hashes
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 282, in _download_http_url
    for chunk in download.chunks:
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 168, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/utils.py", line 88, in response_chunks
    decode_content=False,
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 442, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Does anyone has encountered the same situation just like me ?

Answer (score 0):

Read time out happens when the internet connection is not stable. Please check that. You can also try increasing the default timeout as follows:

```
pip --default-timeout=100 install tensorflow
```